# Permission to create directory remotely - PHP FTP

Tags: php, ubuntu, ftp

What permissions should a remote folder have so I can use FTP via PHP to upload files?

Comment: You probably need to make the user owner of the directory.

Comment: No changes should be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not terribly secure but:

root apache drwxrwx---

Answer (score 0):

you need the permissions to be 777 (full permissions for read,write,execute)
in ubentu you can do the following:
chmod {options} filename
for more information and help visit the official ubuntu documentation:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions